# Why do accelerations due to gravity and external forces get added during upward motion?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gravity, acceleration

> Suppose there is guy in an elevator, who has a mass of 100kg. The elevator is ascending with an acceleration of $10m/s^2$.

What would be the apparent weight of the guy?

Now, my resources tell me that it can be found out by addding the acceleration due to gravity ie. 9.8 and acceleration of the elevator, giving us the apparent weight as $$W=100(9.8+10)=1980N$$

Why do they get added? Isn’t the acceleration of the elevator upwards, while gravity is acting downward? By that logic, they should get subtracted.

I know, intuitively that an object moving with upward acceleration experiences more force, and one moving downward experiences lesser force. But what is the real reason behind this?

Comment: Hint: The apparent weight is just the normal force acting on the person. Can you use Newton's second law to solve for this force?

Comment: Why are you adding 10 when the elevator acceleration is 5?

Comment: @BobD it was a typo. Fixed it

Comment: elevator pushing you upwards pushes against your feet, you feel gravity pushing against your feet, so you add them